# Pythonic way to find integer in list of strings

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array as follows:

```
hour = ['01','02','12']
```

and I want

```
h = 1
str(h) in hour
```

to return `True`. What would be the most "Pythonic" way to do this? I could of course pad `h` with a zero, but is there a better way?

Comment: you mean `[int(i) for i in hour]` ?

Comment: `"%02d" % h in hour` ?

Comment: Do you want to change your list, change the value of `h`, or change the condition you're checking?

Comment: @khelwood the list should be untouched, `h` can be changed.

Comment: So something like `h = '%02d'%h`? (convert the int to a two-digit string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is that the type and structure of data should reflect the model you have in mind. So, if your model is that hours are integers in the range 1..24, or whatever, you should model them that way:

```
hours = [ int(hr) for hr in hour ]
```

then things like:

```
h in hours
```

become clean and obvious.

Comment: What if the items in `hour` cannot be cast to int?

Comment: Then surely your data doesn't match the model that you have in your mind? If so, there are a number of options, depending on where the hour list of strings came from:  1. Just fail if it was part of the program (the dev should fix his code,) 2. If from a user, try/except, print a nice error message, 3. if from a db, etc, print a log message and exit or ignore depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [i for i in hour if h == int(i)]:
    print("found it")
```

`[i for i in hour if h == int(i)]` is a list comprehension which basically means generating a list from an iterable object. It looks into `hours` which is a list which is iterable, and one at a time checks if the value is the same as `h`. We cast it to `int(i)` because we are comparing ints and `i` is a string.

In python an empty list `[]` returns false when using in if statements. So by combining a list comprehension, it allows us to quickly check if there is a value we care about or not. If  there's a list, that means the list comprehension found a value we care about.

Comment: Looks much better!